# Getting json using REST through SSL

Tags: java, android, curl

To connect to server using php, I just use cUrl like this

```
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 320,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 320,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Content-Type: application/json', "Authorization: aaa:bbb", 'X_FORWARDED_FOR: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])
));
```

But I have to do it in Android. Currently I am using HttpsURLConnection, but I get authentification error 400. What am I doing wrong? Here is a code snippet:

```
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type: ", "application/json");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization: ", "aaa:bbb");
        conn.addRequestProperty("X_FORWARDED_FOR: ", getLocalIpAddress().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect using `HttpGet()` like this

```
    HttpClient conn = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getter = new HttpGet(link + 
            appendix);
    Log.d("Request", link+appendix);
    getter.addHeader("Content-Type ", "application/json");
    getter.addHeader("Authorization ", "xxx:yyy");
    getter.addHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR ", "0.0.0.0");
```